# Is there a typo in "Using interruption for cancellation" in Java Concurrency in Practice

Tags: java, interrupt

In the book, Java Concurrency in Practice by Brian Goetz et al, the example on page 141 (2006):

> 7.5: Using interruption for cancellation.

```
class PrimeProducer extends Thread {
}
...
public void cancel() { interrupt(); }
```

The confusing thing is that the book states that Threads should implement an *Interruption Policy*, while Runnable / Callable tasks should implement a *Cancellation Policy*.

**Yet here we are with a `cancel()` method inside of a Thread object.** What's up with that? A few pages before, an example with Runnable is given (7.1) with `cancel()`. In the case of tasks, I would expect to see a qualified `interrupt()` like this:

```
public void cancel() { Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); }
```

---

Extra, semi-relevant information

I am using an ExecutorService, so I deal with tasks (not threads--except for a thread factory for the ExecutorService), but I could not find any could examples of a full ExecutorService shutdown (of many threads) in the book.

My methods for starting tasks and stopping them are:

```
Map<CancellableRunnable, Future<?>> cancellableFutures = new HashMap<>(); // keep track of refs to tasks for stop()
public void init() {
  Future<?> future = myExecutorService.submit(myTask);
  cancellableFutures.put(myTask, future);
}

public void stop() {
  for (Future task : cancellableFutures.values()) {
    task.cancel(true); // also a confusing step. Should it be cancel() on Future or cancel() on task (Runnable/Callable)?
  }
}
```

Comment: This is an important topic, but what you are asking is not clear. You seem to be unhappy with threads/ book explanation in general, but what exactly is the question?

Comment: @Jaywalker Help me out. What exactly is unclear to you? In other words, why is there a cancellation policy in a Thread object? I would expect it to be in a task (Runnable/Callable) as the book suggests. Assumption on my part: a cancellation policy is just a method. Not here to bash the book. Certainly a good book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The confusing thing is that the book states that Threads should implement an Interruption Policy

Right,

```
class MyThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void interrupt() { ... }
}
```

> while Runnable / Callable tasks should implement a Cancellation Policy.

Right,

```
// FutureTask = Runnable (for run) + Future<Void> (for cancel(boolean))
class MyTask extends FutureTask<Void> {
    @Override
    public boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) { ... }

    @Override
    public void run() { ... }
}
```

> Yet here we are with a cancel() method inside of a Thread object.

`Thread` is both `Thread` and `Runnable`, so both `interrupt` (to interrupt *this* thread) and `cancel` (to cancel *this* task, the task currently being run by this thread) should be defined.

```
public class Thread implements Runnable { ... }
```

The `PrimeProducer` example is a bit confusing because it assumes the task defined in `PrimeProducer` will be used outside `PrimeProducer`.

```
class PrimeProducer extends Thread {

    public void run() { 
        try {
            BigInteger p = BigInteger.ONE;
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
                queue.put(p = p.nextProbablePrime()); 
        } catch (InterruptedException consumed) {
            /* Allow thread to exit */
        }
    }

    public void cancel() { interrupt(); }

}
```

It's very reasonable and accurate since we can do

```
Runnable runnable = new PrimeProducer();
new Thread(runnable).start();
```

It's rarely the case, though. It's highly likely we would simply go with

```
new PrimeProducer().start();
```

which would make the task we define in `run` context-aware and `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` and `isInterrupted()` would mean the same. That's what your confusion over `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` and `interrupt()` comes from.

Comment: Nice answer. Correct me if I am wrong: I should implement a `boolean cancel(boolean)` in a `MyThread extends Thread` that is used by my `MyThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory` that is passed to my `ExecutorService`. Then when calling `stop()` (from my code example), I can call `Future.cancel(true)` (`Future<?>` returned from a `submit(Runnable)`, which is confusingly `void`), which  will run the **Cancellation Policy** AND **Interruption Policy** (in that order), which could trigger an `InterruptionException` that I can catch in the try block of the `myTask`. Phew.

Comment: @JonathanKomar I think `cancel` in `Thread` makes sense only when you know exactly what task the thread will be working on (when the thread is bound to a particular task type). Otherwise, `cancel` should be implemented by a task itself

Comment: I think that we are mixing two different levels of abstraction. Thread is lower level than FutureTask. Also, Runnable which is implemented by Thread doesn't have any cancel() method. Neither does Callable. Task and FutureTask are at a different level of abstraction. The "cancel" method comes from the "Future" interface. If you are using Future or Task, why would you need to work with Thread class directly?

Comment: @Jaywalker You might be hitting the nail on the head. The relationship between Future.cancel()/FutureTask.cancel(), Runnable, Cancellable, Thread, interrupt(), Interruption Policy and Cancellation Policy is confusing. Understanding that better would yield cleaner programs, I think.

Comment: @JonathanKomar, I understand the confusion now. I guess if you re-read this sentence from your question: "Threads should implement an Interruption Policy, while Runnable / Callable tasks should implement a Cancellation Policy". The keyword to look out for is "tasks" in "Runnable/ Callable tasks" phrase. We should simplify it to: "Thread implementations should consider interruptions and tasks should consider cancellation". Don't mix Runnable and Callable with task, as the two interfaces are used for more than just that.

Answer (score 2):

> In the case of tasks, I would expect to see a qualified interrupt() like this:
>
> ```
> public void cancel() { Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); }
> ```

That interrupts your own thread, not the thread running the task. There's no point in interrupting yourself if you want something else to stop what it's doing: you can simply stop what you're doing instead.

(You might interrupt the current thread, for example, if you have just caught an `InterruptedException`, and want to preserve the fact that the thread was interrupted. But you don't use this as a mechanism to *start* the interruption).

Comment: Except that that code is found within a task, just to make that clear. It is called from outside. Would it still refer back to the calling thread in that case?

Comment: Yes, Thread.currentThread() is *the* current thread. Threads cannot call methods on each other; they can only interact via shared data.

Comment: @Jaywalker of course threads can call methods on each other: they are objects, so provided a thread has a reference to the other thread, it can call its methods.

Comment: I meant that the method being invoked cannot have the stackframe of another thread. I was referring to thread not as a Java class, but an actual OS level object that is running code.

Answer (score 0):

To correctly close a thread, you have to ask it to close itself by calling `thread.interrupt()` and the thread should periodically check `thread.isInterrupted()` method.

See more details in [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html).

For your example, you have an `ExecutorService myExecutorService`. To close all submitted threads (along with *thread pool* itself), you could call `myExecutorService.shutdown()`. As a result, the thread pool calls `thread.interrupt()` for all threads.

To stop required threads only, you do correct calling `future.cancel(true)`. In this case, your *thread pool* will be alive and will able to submit another task.

Comment: That's cool and addresses part of the question, but does not address the Runnable/Cancellable aspect of the question. The relationship between **Cancellation Policy** and **Interruption Policy** is critical to my question, and in my opinion, is also not didactically explained in the book.